# iOS 9 "Back-To-App" button quickly disappears

Tags: ios, air, ios9, flash-builder

I made an iPad app using Flash Builder and Adobe AIR and it has been working fine. Recently I updated to iOS 9.2, I noticed that when I launch my app from Safari, the button of "Back to Safari" only shows for less than half a second and quickly disappears. I tried this function in other apps, such as launching any app from iTunes, that button always sticks there for a long time.

I did some research and haven't found anything so far. I am hoping to get some help here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you find something? My app doesn't even show the Back to button when I open another app from within it.

Comment: If I use default settings in descriptor xml file back arrow exists, but has black color what is not suitable to me due to my app has black background on top of the screen. I tried UIStatusBarStyle=UIStatusBarStyleLightContent and bar color became light, but the back arrow now disappears after splash screen. It exists while splash is shown and when the app is loaded it disappears.